# Gearman: Run both client and worker on same machine?

Tags: php, ubuntu, gearman

I just manage to install gearman on my local Ubuntu test environment. I wonder if I could in any way run both the worker and the client at the same computer, while in development stage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself; but as Gearman runs by default on port 4730, there should be no clashes, and the default connection is to the local host, so I wouldn't imagine any problems running them both on the same server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run both the worker and client on the same machine. In fact, there are several examples on the Gearman website that does exactly that. In my development environment, I have workers and clients setup to run on the same machine, then further up in the stack (demo, stage) the stack starts to look more like production where there are multiple machines in the mix utilizing virtual machines.

Works the same either way.